# How can I get the index of an element and return it from my template in Vue Js?

Tags: vue.js

```
<template> 
   <select class="form-control" id="sel2" v-model="genre_id">
              <option v-for="genre in genres" v-bind:key="genre.id">
                {{genre.name}}
              </option>
            </select
<template/>
<script>

    data() {
    return {
      genre_id: '',
}}
<script>
```

> The code above gets all the genres and once one is picked it returns the genre.name. My question is, instead of returning the genre.name how can I return the genre.id even though I picked the name on my select form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `value` attribute:

```
<select class="form-control" id="sel2" v-model="genre_id">
  <option v-for="genre in genres" v-bind:key="genre.id" :value="genre.id">
    {{ genre.name }}
  </option>
</select>
```

> The value attribute specifies the value to be sent to a server when a form is submitted.
>
> The content between the opening  and closing  tags is what the browsers will display in a drop-down list. However, the value of the value attribute is what will be sent to the server when a form is submitted.
>
> Note: If the value attribute is not specified, the content will be passed as a value instead.

[Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_value.asp)